# php regex for next page url

Tags: php, regex

I trying to create next &prev page url
I create this function but I can't get the replace for 'page=' or '/page/' correct

```
function paging($currPage=1,$maxPage=9999999999999999){
    $url =  urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $url_next = (preg_replace  ('/([\/page\/|\?page=|\&page=]\d+)/', ($currPage+1),$url ));
    $url_pre = (preg_replace  ('/([\/page\/|\?page=|\&page=]\d+)/',($currPage-1),$url ));
    if ($currPage<=1){
            $back = '';
    }else{       
            $back = '    <li class="previous"><a href="'.$url_pre.'"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> עמוד קודם</a></li>';
    }
    if ($currPage>=$maxPage){
            $next = '';
    }else{      
            $next = '    <li class="next"><a href="'.$url_next.'">עמוד הבא <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>';
    }
$html = ' '
.'  <ul class="pager">' 
.$back.$next
.'  </ul>'
.' ';
    return  $html ;
}
echo paging($_GET["page"]);
```

Comment: Why do you need regex for this?

Comment: Try `'~(?:/page/|[&?]page=)\K\d+~'` for both cases.

Comment: Provide `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variants, please...
You have totaly wrong regular expressions and logic in your code...

Comment: @SergeyKhalitov REQUEST_URI is site.com/page/22 or site.com/page.php?page=3 or site.com?this=ta&page=44 I'm looking for page+1 url

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix the regex like this:

```
'~(?:/page/|[&?]page=)\K\d+~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xoSLfp/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:/page/|[&?]page=)` - a non-capturing group matching either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `/page/` - a literal substring `/page/`
  - `|` - or
  - `[&?]page=` - a `&` or `?` followed with `page=`
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Note that you do not need to escape `/` because `~` is used as a regex delimiter.